# Generic sum macro and nested macro expansion

Tags: c, generics, gcc, preprocessor, c11

I wrote a generic sum macro using the C11 _Generic keyword, but I'm having problems expanding the macro inside other generic function definitions.

Here is the sum macro with all the helper macros:

```
// Helper macros
#define _num_map($, _) $(char)_ $(short)_ $(int)_ $(long)_ $(float)_ $(double)  
#define _comma ,
#define _gencase(_T, _F) _T: _F(_T)
#define _alen(_xs) sizeof(_xs)/sizeof(_xs[0])
#define _generic(_map, _M, _gen, ...) _Generic((_gen), _map(_M, _comma))(__VA_ARGS__)

// Define sum functions
#define _sum_func(_T) __sum_generic_##_T
#define _def_sum(_T) \
_T _sum_func(_T)(_T *xs, size_t len) \
{ \
    _T n = (_T) 0; \
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) \
        n += xs[i]; \
    return n; \
}
_num_map(_def_sum,)
#undef _def_sum
// Define sum$ and suma$ generic macros:
#define _gen_sum(_T) _gencase(_T, _sum_func)
#define sum$(_xs, _len) _generic(_num_map, _gen_sum, (_xs)[0], _xs, _len)
#define suma$(_xs) sum$(_xs, _alen(_xs))
```

`_num_map` is used in order to avoid having to duplicate the types in both the function definition macro and the _Generic expression. It is essentially just a list, with built-in macro-mapping, think of the `_` character as `,` while the `$` character is the mapped macro.

The `$` symbol at the end of `sum$` and `suma$` is just a personal style-guide that means "generic macro, be aware of possible weird compiler errors/warnings if you use it wrong."

This works pretty well and can be used like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    double dubs[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
    double dubs0[] = {};
    printf("Sum: %d\n", suma$(nums));
    printf("DSum: %lf\n", suma$(dubs));
    printf("Zero DSum: %lf\n", suma$(dubs0));
    return 0;
}
```

The problem comes when I attempt to do something like this:

```
// Define avg functions
#define _avg_func(_T) __avg_generic_##_T
#define _def_avg(_T) \
double _avg_func(_T)(_T *xs, size_t len) \
{ \
    return ((double) sum$(xs, len)) / len; \
}
_num_map(_def_avg,)
#undef _def_avg
// Define avg$ and avga$ generic macros:
#define _gen_avg(_T) _gencase(_T, _avg_func)
#define avg$(_xs, _len) _generic(_num_map, _gen_avg, (_xs)[0], _xs, _len)
#define avga$(_xs) avg$(_xs, _alen(_xs))
```

`_num_map(_def_avg,)` fails to expand properly, looking at the output of `gcc -E sum-generic.c` I can see that `_num_map` is treated as a function call when `sum$` is expanded inside `_def_avg`. So for some reason `gcc` doesn't want to keep expanding `_num_map` when it is already expanding `_num_map`.

Resolving the problem involves duplicating `_num_map`:

```
// Define avg functions
#define _avg_map($, _) $(char)_ $(short)_ $(int)_ $(long)_ $(float)_ $(double)  
#define _avg_func(_T) __avg_generic_##_T
#define _def_avg(_T) \
double _avg_func(_T)(_T *xs, size_t len) \
{ \
    return ((double) sum$(xs, len)) / len; \
}
_avg_map(_def_avg,)
#undef _def_avg
// Define avg$ and avga$ generic macros:
#define _gen_avg(_T) _gencase(_T, _avg_func)
#define avg$(_xs, _len) _generic(_avg_map, _gen_avg, (_xs)[0], _xs, _len)
#define avga$(_xs) avg$(_xs, _alen(_xs))
```

I don't like this solution for three reasons:

- `avg$` should inherit the list of acceptable input types from `sum$` as it will only support the types that `sum$` supports
- Because the list of input types are identical, we end up with more code duplication.
- Having macros like `_num_map` that are used everywhere is nice for when you just need "a function that take numeric types" or you could do something like `_integer_map` and `_floating_map` for the other types, which lets you easily categorize the types. Now you have to duplicate everything which makes it less useful for categorization globally.

Cheating with `#define _avg_map _num_map` does not work, neither does nesting `_num_map` deeper.

So my question is, is there a way to force the `gcc` compiler to continue expanding `_num_map` *inside* `_num_map(_def_avg)`? Or do I just have to duplicate `_num_map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, C macros are never recursive. 6.10.3.4 p 2 reads:

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of
>   the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s
>   preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested
>   replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not
>   replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no
>   longer available for further replacement even if they are later
>   (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token
>   would otherwise have been replaced.